# Keras.Net - Model predict doesn't return when model is global variable

Tags: c#, machine-learning, autoencoder, ml.net

I am trying to run a model on a camera feed.
Therefore I want to load in the model and store it as a global variable and use it while the frames come in.
It works when I load in the model for each frame (in the process function) but when I store the model as a global variable, the predict line hangs indefinitely so it feels like resources are being released when they shouldn't be.

How I can get this to work?

```
private BaseModel model;

public void Initialize()
{
    model = BaseModel.LoadModel(networkPath);
}

public dynamic Process(Mat frame)
{
    var mat = new Mat();
    Cv2.Resize(frame, mat, inputSize);
    var image_in = mat.Convert(np.uint8);

    image_in = np.asfarray(image_in, np.float32);
    image_in /= 256;

    image_in = np.expand_dims(image_in, 0);

    var output = model.Predict(image_in);

    output = output[0];

    return (Input: image_in, Output: output);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue for us had to do with using the PythonEngine in mutliple threads.
Now we initialise using

```
if (!PythonEngine.IsInitialized) { PythonEngine.Initialize(); }
model = BaseModel.LoadModel(networkPath);
PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();
```

In our worker thread we have

```
using (Py.GIL()) {}
```

wrapped around our code.

Answer (score 0):

Since I ran into the problem and found various threads with similar issues I´d like to emphasize what´s already written in the docs:

https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET/blob/main/README.md#multi-threading-must-read

"Note that you must call a method of np before calling PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads() in order for the PythonEngine to be initialized. So, for instance, if you want to initialize an inherently multi-threaded .Net Core Web API at startup, do something like this:"

```
np.arange(1); // force numpy initialisation, required before PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads()
Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads(); // allow different threads
```

Without the forced numpy initialisation BeginAllowThreads() might not work in your projects.